# How can I do to check if a list of lists is empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list :

```
a = [[], [], []]
```

and that one :

```
b = [[], [2], []]
```

I would like to check if a and b are empty. I mean for me a is empty and b is not. How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Using `any`:

```
>>> any([[], [], []])
False
>>> any([[], [2], []])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for "empty" using `not any`

```
>>> not any(a)
True
>>> not any(b)
False
```